# Apps Script | Adding drive links to sheets (only new files)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have modified some code that allows me to generate a list of all hyperlinks in a specified Google Drive within a sheet (ordered by the last updated column).

I would love some help in adapting this script:

1. to update (and sort) automatically only when a new file is added to the folder or modified so I don't need to click the "List files/ Folders drop-down" everytime I add a new file
2. Combine the name and the URL columns so that the hyperlink text is the file name and not a URL string

I have added the code below. Appreciate any assistance! Thank you

```js
  function onOpen() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('List Files/Folders')
    .addItem('List All Files and Folders', 'listFilesAndFolders')
    .addToUi();
};

function listFilesAndFolders(){
  var folderId = '1ROr5fDfzwZaT-_izAAag2qOnoY4k-n43'
  
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    
    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name","Type" ,"Date", "URL", "Last Updated"]);
    
    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
 
  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var folderId = childFolder.getId();
    data = [ 
      parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getName(),
      "Folder",
      childFolder.getDateCreated(),
      childFolder.getUrl(),
      childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
   
    ];
    // Write
    sheet.appendRow(data);
    
    // List files inside the folder
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getName(),
        "Files",
        childFile.getDateCreated(),
        childFile.getUrl(),
        childFile.getLastUpdated(),
       
      ];

        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F");

  // Sorts descending by column B
 range.sort({column: 6, ascending: false});


      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }

 
};
```

Comment: There is no trigger that fires on loading of a file into a folder.

Comment: Thanks Cooper! That is good to know. Is there a way for the re-load of all files to happen upon opening of the sheet?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Sorry to clarify - instead of a user needing to select the 'List All Files and Folders' button in the nav menu to reload wondering what I would need to change for this to happen automatically when the spreadsheet is opened?

Comment: You can run List All Files and Folders everytime you open with an installable onOpen trigger.

Comment: Too easy! Found a way to make it work. Thanks Cooper

Comment: Hi Cooper! Hoping you might be able to assist with an improvement I am trying to make to this script. I want to be able to list files that were updated in the last 60 days only - I have tried to build out the filtered condition with no luck. Any pointers yu can advise. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the Activity API might have that information.